# How to keep ec2 instance running in auto-scaling group for at least an hour?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

In ASG it makes no sense to terminate an on-demand instance until it runs (1, 2, n) hour(s) 59 mins because you pay for time to full hour anyway.

How to configure termination to make sure that billed time won't be wasted?

I know about ClosestToNextInstanceHour, but it doesn't always help: if you have instanceA which is running 5 h 20 mins and instanceB running 5 h 10 min it'll select for termination instanceA whilst the desired result is not to scale down ~40 more minutes.

Another idea I found so far is to configure scale-down to 'Execute policy when ... *metric_name* <= x% for **3600** seconds' but it won't work as expected, e.g. when the instance was started 1h 20 mins before the policy should be executed.

So how I can do it?

Comment: In most cases this is going to be severely premature optimization.

Comment: Even though you've paid for an hour of EC2 time, I would check to see if the EBS pricing is charging you in full hour increments aS well and if it's not you might be saving some cost by the instance being terminated and giving back the used EBS allocation.

Comment: If you don't need the capacity, the mere fact that you've already paid for it does not seem like a logically sound reason to keep it... and I say you don't need it, because if you did need it, you wouldn't be scaling down.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have in mind two cases: 
1.Assume X servers is enough to process the current load, but X+1 gives benefit - lesser processing time, etc. The benefit isn't big enough to pay for it, but big enough not to waste it.
2. if the server started at 01:00, at 01:30 we'll terminate it due to low load, then at 01:45 we're starting it again - I'd prefer to keep server turned 'on' that time to avoid being billed twice.

Comment: @Putnik Don't forget to count the time it takes to implement this. A few hours at $100/hour is going to obliterate the pennies you save this way. If you've got a lot of server churn, you should be starting with adjusting your cooldowns first.

Comment: @ceejayoz My hourly rate is $10 only :( And it's quite high for my location